# How to remove the text Laravel appearing next to Favicon

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I have a minor issue where there is a text "Laravel" appearing on my header.

Laravel Version is 10.13.5

Comment: That's likely the HTML `<title>` element, and is not an issue... You just need to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

The text next to favicon is just the title of the page. You can find it in your layout file (by default `app.blade.php`)

```
<title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
```

By default, Laravel gives `APP_NAME` from `.env` as title. You can either change it to your app name OR directly modify the title as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Locate the HTML layout file: In Laravel, the HTML layout file is usually located in the resources/views/welcome.blade.php or  resources/views/layouts directory. Look for a file named app.blade.php

Search Laravel and delete.